# R installation on Ubuntu, how to fix this error message?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, r

I'm quite new to Unix systems and I just can't understand why I'm having this problem during the installation of R on Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa.

I have installed R using the following procedure:

- checked for the presence of the string `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/` in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file;
- used commands: `sudo apt-get update` and then the command `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`

When I run R in the terminal or when I try to install packages from RStudio this message shows up:

`/usr/bin/R: line 248: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory`

For every package I try to install the error "installation of package had non-zero exit status" shows up and the reason the package is not installed is the absence of the directory showed above.

Inside the directory `/usr/lib/R/etc` the file `ldpaths` is present.

Is there a solution to this problem? Sorry for the poorness of my indications, if other information is needed I will update my question with screenshots or command lines.

Edit: I post the output of the command `apt-cache policy r-base-core`

```
r-base-core:
  Installed: 4.2.0-1.2004.0
  Candidate: 4.2.0-1.2004.0
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.1.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```

Checking for broken links with `symlinks` tool I found this:

```
dangling: /usr/lib/R/etc/repositories -> /etc/R/repositories
dangling: /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf -> /etc/R/Makeconf
absolute: /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron -> /etc/R/Renviron
dangling: /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron.site -> /etc/R/Renviron.site
dangling: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths -> /etc/R/ldpaths
dangling: /usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site -> /etc/R/Rprofile.site
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be missing some packages. Follow these steps and see what happens: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: I used the same procedure (I tried also more than once) and the problem is always the same

Comment: Do you have an `R_ARCH` or `R_HOME` environment variable? is it possible that one of them contains some non-printing character?

Comment: Using `env` command both `R_ARCH` and `R_HOME` are not present.

Comment: OK so what happens if you manually source the file into your shell (`. /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths`)

Comment: Same error: `bash: /usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths: No such file or directory`, even if, as I wrote in the question, the file exists in that directory.

Comment: It looks like the file should actually be a symbolic link (`/usr/lib/R/etc/ldpaths -> /etc/R/ldpaths`) - is the link perhaps broken?

Comment: I used symlinks tool in order to find broken links in the folder `/usr/lib/R/etc` and actually it shows that all the files in this directory are broken links (I will add the output in the question as it's better than in the comments)

Comment: Edit: I found and deleted those broken links, uninstalled R and reinstalled it following this steps: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/. After reinstalling, the broken links are there again and the same error occurs.

Comment: @Marco the target files `/etc/R/*` belong to the r-base-core package - so I'd try re-installing that (`sudo apt install --reinstall r-base-core`)

Comment: Nothing changes, I think in the next days I will try to completely remove and reinstall Ubuntu itself and see if this will solve the problem.